# Returning records in List<T> format in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, arraylist

My asp.net code calls a DataAccessLayer class (SubscriberDAL.cs) that does that database query & returns records. I am calling that class from my Search.aspx.cs page. The SubscriberDAL.cs method returns records in List format. How can I capture those records from my Search.aspx.cs page?

So in the code sample below, **PremsubList** returns a list array. How can I view those in Search.aspx.cs ?

My code is:

**Search.aspx.cs:**

```
PremCustomerMgr.GetSubscriberList(sub);
```

**SubscriberDAL.cs**

```
public static List<PremSubscriber.Subscriber> GetSubscriberList(PremSubscriber.Subscriber QueryData)
{
    try
    {
        List<PremSubscriber.Subscriber> PremsubList = new List<PremSubscriber.Subscriber>();

        PremCustomerDAL.SearchSubscriberData(PremsubList, QueryData);
        return PremsubList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GCException gcEx = new GCException("Exception - PremCustomerMgr.GetSubscriberList", ex);
        throw psEx;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the result of your method call as the `Datasource` for a control on Search.aspx.

For example, if you add a `DataGridView` to your page, you can do something like this:

```
MyDataGridView.Datasource = PremCustomerMgr.GetSubscriberList(sub); 
MyDataGridView.Databind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Uh...

```
var MyResults = PremCustomerMgr.GetSubscriberList(sub);
```

?

Next, do something with MyResults.

Maybe you need to clarify what you mean with "*How can I capture those records from my Search.aspx.cs page*". Explain "capture"? Or maybe you can explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve? Maybe post some more (relevant!) code?